# Cut a string based on a delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a for each loop to iterate through a few thousand rows of data that all have this style: `1010-2020-3030`

I want to break this string apart into 3 cells using the hyphen as a delimiter. I want to put 1010 in the AI cell, 2020 in the AJ cell, and 3030 in the AK cell.

I've searched all over Google and combined a few examples I found but I am getting an object error 1004. This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Cell_Loop()
Dim cell As Range

  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I3000")
    Selection.TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("AI" & cell), _           '(I'm trying to use cell as a variable to iterate through.)
          DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=True, _
          Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, _
          Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, _
          OtherChar:="-"
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the [`Split` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528.aspx).

Comment: Why are you looping through nearly 300 cells when TexttoColumns will do all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextToColumns can handle all of the nearly 3000 entries in column I and spit them out to columns AI:AK.

```
Sub Split_Without_Loop()

  With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("AI2"), _
          DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          Tab:=False, _
          Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, _
          Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, _
          OtherChar:="-"
  End With

End Sub
```

Some of the recorded code can be eliminated for clarity as it does not pertain to this operation.

Your original problem was that you were looping through the cells into a range variable representing each cell but then using `Selection` to govern the TextToColumns command. There was either nothing selected or the current selected cell didn't contain hyphen and in any event, you were not changing the selection to the cell being iterated through in the loop. It probably would have worked with `cell.TextToColumns _` instead of `Selection.TextToColumns _` but the looping would have slowed it down immensely.

[image]

Comment: Does exactly what I need it to. Thank you!!